# Work around for browser popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to open a window based on a server call, but that window is blocked by browser as popup for certain users.

Here is the sample of code of what I am trying to do

```
<a onclick="validateuser()"></a>
```

In validate user, I am sending request to an external server.

The server sends response to another method `openwindow()`

In `openwindow()` I am calling `window.open` to open the particular page.

When I call `openwindow()` directly on `onclick`, the user is not blocked by popup.

Comment: go to your favourit search engine and search for that problem.. and the sample code should be code and not text ^^

Answer (score 0):

This can't be fixed - the behaviour is by design. You need to tie your pop-up directly to some user action (like clicking a button) or find another way. You could open up a `<div>` with an `<iframe>` inside, perhaps.